# How to search from a list inside a dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

if I have a dictionary
    `<string, List<string>>`. (ex. <12345, List<"ABC", "456", "123">>
and I want to pull out the key '12345' where I have "456" in the list of strings for each entry in the list.
So my result would be another list.
Wouldn't this be done with a linq statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wouldn't this be done with a linq statement?

Sure. It won't be *efficient*, but it's pretty simple:

```
var input = "456";
var matchingKeys = dictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(input))
                             .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

If you want it to be *efficient* as well, you should store the reverse mapping too, and update both together.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be easily done without LINQ, although as Jon mentionned, this is not going really going to be efficient if your Dictionary contains a lot of keys/values. Here's an Extension method that does exactly the same as Jon's answer, without LINQ :

```
public static List<TKey> GetMatchingKeys<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, ICollection<TValue>> src, TValue toFind)
{
    List<TKey> returnVal = new List<TKey>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, ICollection<TValue>> kv in src)
    {
        if (kv.Value.Contains(toFind))
        {
            returnVal.Add(kv.Key);
        }
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```